# How do I return a specific json field?

Tags: python, json

How do I get this function to just return the value "Accounting"?

```
def getowner():
       z = [{u'_ref': u'network/ZG5zLm5ldHdvcmskMTAuMTAwLjEwMC4wLz90jLzA:10.100.100.0/24/default', u'extattrs': {u'Owner': {u'value': u'Accounting'}}}]
       return ((h['value']) for h in z['Owner'])


z = getowner()
print z
```

Im getting error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `z` variable is an array (of one element) because of the surrounding square brackets. Here is how I would access what you have:

```
>>> z[0]['extattrs']['Owner']['value']
u'Accounting'
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
def getowner():
   z = [{u'_ref': u'network/ZG5zLm5ldHdvcmskMTAuMTAwLjEwMC4wLz90jLzA:10.100.100.0/24/default', u'extattrs': {u'Owner': {u'value': u'Accounting'}}}]
   return z[0]['extattrs']['Owner']['value']

z = getowner()
print z
```